# Reduce graph by removing transitive nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, bipartite

I'm working on a problem that requires removing transitive nodes in a graph. More specifically I need to reduce the number of edges by removing the nodes from the path between two sets of nodes.

Picture says a thousand words so here is what I'm trying to do

[image: reducing transitive nodes]

The graph contains 3 types of nodes (Ai, Bi, Ci). I'd like to reduce the graph by removing all the nodes Bi on a path between nodes Ai and Ci, whilst preserving reachability between the Ai,Ci nodes.

This is a tripartite graph, indeed, and I'm wondering if there is an efficient algorithm that can reduce it as per the description shown in the attached picture.

Comment: Why the graph is tripartite?

Comment: Since you need to remove all the B nodes, and you need to add an edge A-C for every pair of edges A-B-C, I'm afraid you can't do better than iterating over all the B-nodes, and for every B-node, iterating over all its A-neighbours and all its C-neighbours.

Comment: @Stef yes, that is sort of my current approach, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient algorithm. It seems to me that there must be one, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: How are you storing this graph, what datastructure? Can we identify clearly if a node is type A, B and C or do we need to partition it?

Answer (score 0):

If we let `A` denote the adjacency matrix between the As and Bs and `B` denote the adjacency matrix between the Bs and Cs, then the adjacency matrix of the resulting graph is the Boolean matrix product `AB`. In theory the fast matrix multiplication algorithms apply (if you have dense matrices), but in practice I doubt that they'll help much.